# Converting restId format type to old Outlook HexEntryId type

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-calendar, format-conversion

Back in the days when we did a calendar synchronisatie via Outlook this gave us IDs of the form:

```
00000000ABC72AACB341FF4F9886BAAC125E772807007591CF0335B23144ADC7FCD71BA6E2FC00000000010D00007591CF0335B23144ADC7FCD71BA6E2FC00009957CF160000
```

We later upgraded the code to use Exchange Web Services, and for a smooth transistion we kept the old IDs in custom event properties, and therefore had to convert EWS `EntryIds` like this:

```
<soapenv:Body>
  <mes:ConvertId DestinationFormat="HexEntryId">
    <mes:SourceIds>
      <typ:AlternateId Format="EwsId" Id="AAMkADI2ZGIwY2FlLTA1NDQtNGFhYi1hNDJmLWEyMGJhZWU5NmM2YgBGAAAAAACrxyqss0H/T5iGuqwSXncoBwB1kc8DNbIxRK3H/NcbpuL8AAAAAAENAAB1kc8DNbIxRK3H/NcbpuL8AAJ2Kv4fAAA=" Mailbox="timetelldev@timetell.nl"/>
    </mes:SourceIds>
  </mes:ConvertId>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Response:

```
 <ResponseMessages>
   <ConvertIdResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
     <ResponseCode>NoError</ResponseCode>
     <AlternateId type="t:AlternateIdType" Format="HexEntryId" Id="00000000ABC72AACB341FF4F9886BAAC125E772807007591CF0335B23144ADC7FCD71BA6E2FC00000000010D00007591CF0335B23144ADC7FCD71BA6E2FC0002762AFE1F0000" Mailbox="timetelldev@timetell.nl"/>
   </ConvertIdResponseMessage>
 </ResponseMessages>
```

We are now moving to MS Graph and I need to be able to convert the new `restId` format to the old Outlook ones using [translateExchangeIds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) (according to [Exchange Web Services (EWS) to Microsoft Graph API mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-exchange-web-services-api-mapping)).
But there is no such thing as the `HexEntryId` format type. I tried several combinations with no luck.

(How) can I convert the MS Graph REST IDs to these HexEntryId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to first convert `restId` to `entryId` by calling

```
POST /me/translateExchangeIds

{
    "inputIds": [
        "{restId}"
    ],
    "sourceIdType": "restId",
    "targetIdType": "entryId"
}
```

It will return `targetId` in form of `entryId`.

Now convert `entryId` to `hexEntryId`

- Take `targetId` and remove an integer from the end of the string.
  This integer indicates how many characters `=` must be added to the
  end of the string.
- Add `=` at the end of the string (how many times - from previous step)
- Replace `_` with `/`
- Replace `-` with `+`
- Convert string from base64 to byte array
- Convert byte array to hex string

The final hex string should be your `hexEntryId`